# Blocking admin user sign-in using Microsoft Graph

Tags: azure, powershell, microsoft-graph-api

I am writing a Powershell script, which is leveraging the Microsoft Graph using an App Registration. The script is getting a list of admins within our tenancy and it's checking to see if they have logged in within a 30 day time-frame. If they haven't, a notification email is sent and their account sign-in is toggled to blocked.

The email notification part of the code works as intended, but it's the sign-in toggle I am having trouble getting to work from Powershell, since I am getting a 'Forbidden 403' error when I run the code.

I've tried running the sign-in toggle using the Graph Explorer and it worked as intended.

```
#CREATE ACCESS TOKEN
    $token = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri https://login.microsoftonline.com/$tenant/oauth2/token?api-version=1.0 -Method Post -Body @{"grant_type" = "client_credentials"; "resource" = "https://graph.microsoft.com/"; "client_id" = $clientID;  "client_secret" = $clientSecret} 

    $Headers = @{ 
'authorization'="Bearer $($Token.access_token)" 
}

    #Url
    $apiAccount = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/$userPrincipalName"

#TOGGLE SIGN-IN
    $blockaccount = "{
    ""accountEnabled"": ""false""
}"

Invoke-RestMethod -Headers $headers -Uri $apiAccount -Body $blockaccount -ContentType "application/json" -Method Patch


# My App Registration permissions (Application)

AuditLog.Read.All
Directory.ReadWrite.All
Mail.Send
User.ReadWrite.All
```

When running the code, I get a 'Forbidden 403' error. I've even tried adding the App Registration to the Helpdesk Admin role in Azure and that didn't yield any success either.

Comment: Did you tried with [Directory Writers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/users-groups-roles/directory-assign-admin-roles#directory-writers) role?

Comment: I don't have Directory Writers in my tenancy from what I can see. I have tried using Privileged Role admin, but with no success. I updated my App Registration with AdministrativeUnit.ReadWrite.All and that didn't work either.

Answer (score 1):

On the Documentation page, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-update you’ll see an important hint when updating users. It says you’ll need the delegated `Directory.AccessAsUser.All` permission to update the **passwordProfile** property.

My guess is that you’ll also need that (with an admin logged-in) to enable/disable the login status.